# Término o expresión en español para "burglary"

Tags: traducción, lenguaje-jurídico

En más de un diccionario o traductor, la palabra *burglary* se expresa como robo. Sin embargo, no es precisamente un robo pues implica un ingreso a un hogar. Quizá puede verse mejor en español (al menos en Colombia según la ASALE) como la acción de un [apartamentero](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=apartamentero), e incluso, según he interpretado los casos leídos, el ingreso a una casa puede ser buscando otro acto delictivo, así que la traducción de robo parece quedarse corta. ¿Hay palabras o frases que ayuden a plantear de una manera más adecuada la traducción?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Actualizo para incluir una palabra que he descubierto hoy y que, aunque la RAE la retiró del diccionario en 1992, lo cierto es que viene que ni pintada. Copio definición del NTLLE:

> **volata** m. *Germ.* Ladrón que hurta por ventana o tejado.

Es decir, un *burglar* de toda la vida.

Una pena que el verbo "volatear" no tenga absolutamente nada que ver con esta palabra.

---

Primero de todo, analicemos la [definición de burglary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burglary):

> Acceso ilícito a un edificio o emplazamiento *con la intención de cometer una falta o delito*, normalmente robo.

Teniendo en cuenta ese matiz, según el DEJ, la Wikipedia, el Código Penal español y multitud de aseguradoras, el concepto más parecido a *burglary* sería el de (intento de) **robo o atraco con fuerza en las cosas**:

> [**robo con fuerza en las cosas**](https://dej.rae.es/lema/robo-con-fuerza-en-las-cosas)
>
> *Pen.* Modalidad de robo que consiste en apoderarse de cosas muebles ajenas empleando fuerza en las cosas para acceder o abandonar el lugar donde estas se encuentran.
>
> - *La fuerza en las cosas es un concepto normativo, no gramatical, que consiste en utilizar escalamiento, romper pared, techo o suelo, fracturar puerta o ventana, fracturar armarios, arcas u otra clase de muebles u objetos cerrados o sellados, forzar sus cerraduras, descubrir sus claves para sustraer su contenido, usar llaves falsas o inutilizar sistemas específicos de alarma o guarda. CP, arts. 237-241.*

En algunos casos se define como **robo con allanamiento**, aunque no es el término aceptado legalmente.

**No sería válido [allanamiento](https://dej.rae.es/lema/allanamiento1) sin más**, puesto que este concepto solo implica el acceso a una propiedad privada en contra de la voluntad de la persona propietaria. Su equivalente en inglés sería [*trespass to land*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trespass_to_land).
El robo y el allanamiento son delitos distintos, y el segundo no tiene por qué implicar el primero.
En este sentido, y si consultamos de nuevo la página de Wikipedia para *burglary* (enlazada arriba), vemos que el mismo enfoque se aplica en otros países europeos como Finlandia o Suecia.

En el caso de que para el robo no se usase fuerza de ningún tipo, por ejemplo si te dejas la puerta de casa abierta de par en par y alguien entrase y se llevase tu televisor sin romper nada, se calificaría como dos delitos: [hurto](https://dej.rae.es/lema/delito-de-hurto) por un lado (que viene a ser un robo sin violencia ni intimidación) y allanamiento por otro (invasión de la propiedad); aunque en inglés algo así ya no se calificaría como *burglary*.

<sub>Exención de responsabilidad: ignoro hasta qué punto, siendo parte de la RAE, los términos recogidos en el *Diccionario del español jurídico* son usados en todo el ámbito hispanoparlante o solo en España.</sub>